# Stack Exchange using Windows XP?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

A [recent tweet by @StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/453521841492361216) reads:

> Stack Exchange will be offline for a few hours tomorrow while we
>   upgrade our web servers from Windows XP.

[image]

This can't be accurate?

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network) seems to contradict that.

Furthermore, if this is some kind of joke, it seems in poor taste considering that @StackStatus is used for actual status updates to the network.

Late [april-fools](/questions/tagged/april-fools)?

Comment: Ha! Be glad they updated. They were running Windows 98 until the year before last. Anybody remember Windows 98?

Comment: This is just more proof of the awesomeness that is Windows XP.

Comment: Microsoft should have killed Vista first.

Comment: Hey, I just got an awesome email from some poor guy in Nigeria who needs help transferring some money out of the country.  Now, I'm kinda stuck right now and I can't help him out.  Maybe you can?  He said he'd make it worth your while.  Just gimme your email address and I'll forward his mail to you.

Comment: Oh, totally man. Just have him tranfer the funds to my credit card: Superfied Credit Union, account number 5675 116 116 1352, exp. 13/02

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Please don't make fun of us man, we're doing the best we can here. We just never got around to upgrading before.

**Edit:** For those that still don't get it, this was a joke in honor of Windows XP EOL today. We obviously use the more lightweight Windows ME on those servers.

Comment: Excellent. Do you have a timeline for phasing out Trumpet Winsock?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi settle down buddy, one major upgrade at a time, alright?

Comment: So you say [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network) was wrong from the very first revision that claimed "Operating System Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition x64", probably based on [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/our-dedicated-server/)? Jeff did say "Here are the specifications for what will **eventually** become the dedicated stackoverflow.com server" but still...

Comment: Now, Nick, can you please upgrade our PHP framework? Because, c'mon...

Comment: Can I finally get Photoshop plz? I'm sick 'n tired of Paint.

Comment: @ShadowWizard eventually = 6 to 8 years.

Comment: Can the next one be getting my dev workstation off of Windows ME?

Comment: @Stijn - 6 to 8 years?  I didn't realize SE was quite that progressive.  That's almost an aggressive schedule there...

Comment: @NickCraver So that MSO post that says you're using Server 2012 is.. Wrong?

Comment: Well played Nick, guess that StackStatus was held as something too serious to be used to trick us.

Comment: Have you also upgrade the RAM or is it still `640k`?

Comment: Okay, now I am *completely* confused. What do you use? Server 2012, XP or ME?